# Limit of weighted average

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be a finite set of real numbers and $w(x, \theta)$ a weight function such that

$$w(x, \theta) = e^{x\theta}.$$

Denote $a(\theta)$ the weighted average of the $x_i$'s with weights given by $w$, i.e.,
$$a(\theta) = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i e^{x_i\theta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n e^{x_i\theta}}.$$

Intuitively, I think that $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \infty} = \max_i x_i$ and $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow -\infty} = \min_i x_i$ because when $\theta$ is too large, then the relative weight of the maximum value will make all others negligible. I don't know what tools I can use to prove these limits. Is there any trick I can use here?

Comment: Multiply by $e^{-\theta \cdot \max_i x_i}$ on both top and bottom.  Then you can take the limit $\theta \to \infty$ directly.

Comment: Wow, that was really simple. Especially when I already knew the result! I was trying to figure out what kind of complicated result would cause the maximum to appear. It was just the usual multiplication by one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question hope I can help! This might seem very long and wordy but I have just explained things in a lot of detail, its not that horrible don't worry!
Before we begin to answer the question we are going to need to prove a tiny lemma!

$\textbf{Lemma:} $

Let $a_{max}$ = max {$a_1,a_2,a_3,..,a_k$} then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{max}^n}{a_1^n+a_2^n+a_3^n+...+a_k^n} =1$

We will use the following simple law of limits (*) : $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{s_n} = \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to +\infty} s_n }$

Proof of Lemma:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{a_1^n+a_2^n+a_3^n+...+a_k^n}{a_{max}^n} = \lim_{n \to +\infty}((\frac{a_1}{a_{max}})^n + (\frac{a_2}{a_{max}})^n  + ... + (\frac{a_{max}}{a_{max}})^n + ...+ (\frac{a_k}{a_{max}})^n )$

(All we have done is split the sum into its $k$ pieces. And there is one $a_i$ such that $a_{i} = a_{max}$, from definition of $a_{max}. $ Yes this $i$ could be $1,2$ or $k$ but this doesn't matter, the expansion is just for a visual aid. )

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}((\frac{a_1}{a_{max}})^n + (\frac{a_2}{a_{max}})^n  + ... + (\frac{a_{max}}{a_{max}})^n + ...+ (\frac{a_k}{a_{max}})^n)  = \lim_{n \to +\infty}(r_1^n + r_2^n + ... + 1^n + ... + r_k^n)$

Where $r_i := \frac{a_i}{a_{max}}$

Notice that for all i we have $r_i < 1 $

Hence:  $\lim_{n \to +\infty} r_i^n = 0 $ $\forall$ $i $

And then $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(r_1^n + r_2^n + ... + 1^n + ... + r_k^n) =$ 0 + 0 + ... + 1 + ... + 0 = $1$

Hence:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{a_1^n+a_2^n+a_3^n+...+a_k^n}{a_{max}^n} = 1 $ and then from (*) law we finally have:  $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{max}^n}{a_1^n+a_2^n+a_3^n+...+a_k^n} =\frac{1}{1} = 1$

Don't worry! That was the hard part! The rest is easy dont worry! Now onto the last stretch:

Firstly let us define $a_i := e^{x_i} $

$ \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} a(\theta)  = \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i a_i^{\theta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} = \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} (\frac{x_{1}a_1^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} + \frac{x_{2}a_2^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} + ... + \frac{x_{max}a_{max}^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} + ... + \frac{x_{n}a_n^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}})$

This is the same trick as before, writing a sum as all of its components but separately listing the maximum. We must now try to evaluate this limit for each component. We will split these into 2 cases to do seperately. Those with $ a_j \not =  a_{max} $ and then $a_{max} $

$\textbf{Case 1} $

To evaluate $\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} (\frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}) $ for $ a_j \not =  a_{max} :$

Notice that $ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta} $ (the denominator of our components) is greater than $ a_{max}^{\theta} $.

Hence $ \frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}  < \frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{a_{max}^{\theta}}   $ as it has a greater denominator

Hence: $\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}  < \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{a_{max}^{\theta}} $

Now, like before, define $r_j := \frac{a_j}{a_{max}} $ < 1

And hence: $\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}  < \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{a_{max}^{\theta}} =  \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} = a_j \cdot r_j^{\theta} = 0   $

So $\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} (\frac{x_{j}a_j^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}) $ for $ a_j \not =  a_{max}  = 0 $

$\textbf{Case 2} $

$\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} (\frac{x_{max}a_{max}^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}) = \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} x_{max} \cdot \frac{a_{max}^{\theta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} = x_{max} \cdot 1 $ (From the Lemma we proved)

Hence:

$ \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} a(\theta)  = \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i a_i^{\theta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} = \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} (\frac{x_{1}a_1^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} + \frac{x_{2}a_2^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} + ... + \frac{x_{max}a_{max}^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}} + ... + \frac{x_{n}a_n^{\theta}}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}}) = 0 + 0 + ... + x_{max} + ... + 0 = x_{max} $

Finally for  $ \lim_{\theta \to -\infty} a(\theta) $:

Notice $ \lim_{\theta \to -\infty} a(\theta)  =  \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} a(-\theta) = \lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i e^{-x_i\theta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n e^{-x_i\theta}} = -\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n -x_i e^{-x_i\theta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n e^{-x_i\theta}}$ =

$-$Max{$-x_1,-x_2,...,-x_n$} = $- - $Min{$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$} = Min{$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$}

Your intuition was correct!

Hope this helped.

Oskar